# 2d arrays, calling function problems

Tags: c++

I'm doing a task, and I'm having some problems, so help please, u kind people :D
I need to create function that allows input for student grades. In that function, I need to allow only input for 6-10 (passing grades). Then, I need to make a function that calculates lowest grade for student. And, in the end, need to make a function that calculates average grade per student. 
PS : Maybe my ideas are wrong, or u would to something different or better, say it please, I wanna learn. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code and errors :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int input (int [][4], int);
int average (int [][4], int);
int min (int [][4], int);
int main ()
{
    const int wdth = 5;
    int matrix[4][4];
    input (matrix [4][4], wdth);
    average (matrix [4][4], wdth);
    min (matrix [4][4], wdth);
return 0;
}
int input (int matrix[][4], int wdth)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < wdth; i ++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter grades for "<<i+1<<" student:"<<endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < wdth; j ++)
        {
            cin>>matrix[i][j];
            if ((matrix[i][j] < 6) || (matrix[i][j] > 10))
            {
                cout<<"INVALID INPUT!"<<endl;
                return 0;
            }
            //cout<<setw(5);
            cout<<matrix[i][j];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
int average (int matrix[][4], int wdth)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int avrg = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < wdth; i ++)
    {
        cout<<"Calculating average for "<<i+1<<" student: "<<endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < wdth; j ++)
        {
            sum = sum + matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    avrg = sum / 5;
    return 0;
}
int min (int matrix[][4], int wdth)
{
    int temp = 0;
    int MIN = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < wdth; i ++)
    {
        cout<<"Calculating lowest grade for "<<i+1<<" student: "<<endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < wdth; j ++)
        {
            temp = matrix[i][j];
            if (temp < MIN)
            {
                MIN = temp;
            }
        }
     cout<<MIN;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

ERRORS:

```
cpp(11) : error C2664: 'input' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int [][4]'
        Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

cpp(12) : error C2664: 'average' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'int [][4]'
        Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Answer (score 5):

`input (matrix [4][4], wdth);` Here `matrix [4][4]` is an element of the matrix i.e. an `int`. You need to do `input(matrix,wdth);`

Answer (score 3):

```
input (matrix [4][4], wdth);
average (matrix [4][4], wdth);
min (matrix [4][4], wdth);
```

Try it this way. :)

```
input (matrix, wdth);
average (matrix, wdth);
min (matrix, wdth);
```

With `matrix[4][4]` your passing the 4th element of the 4th row. ;)